# Trigger Action from Push Notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, push-notification

I have a cordova application that uses push notification (still using the old plugin :-().

The application uses ngRouter and the navigation is relatively basic - in that I mean that my main menu changes ngView but popups/modals are not part of the navigation and are either triggered by some bound controller property or through a call to a controller function (e.g. `$scope.openMyModal`).

I am trying to be able to call such function on one of my controllers after I received push notification (and the controller is loaded).

I implemented some code using a timeout to broadcast an event which should be caught in the relevant controller and open the modal. Roughly the code is:

In app.js:

```
onNotification() {
   // some code for determining the type of notification
   // then
   setTimeout(function() {
       $rootScope.$broadcast("someEventCode");
   }, 10); // or 1000 in case of cold start
}
```

In MyController.js:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope, $modal,...) {
    $scope.openMyModal = function() { // open modal using $model }

    $scope.on("someEventCode", function() {
        $scope.openMyModal();
    });
}
```

This kind of works but is not consistent/deterministic. For example, in slower devices it may broadcast before the controller is ready to respond to it.

I also tried to set some variable on root scope (in `onNotification`) and in the controller create a function which is called from the markup (e.g. `{{isNotificationReady()}}`) but this also doesn't work well.

Another approach was to use double notifications - set a flag in root scope when the notification arrives, wait for an event from the target controller (indicating it is loaded) and then, at `$rootScope` again, if flag is set, broadcast the "open dialog" event (and delete the flag). Following this approach, I am not sure how to trigger the "loaded" event so I use a function from the markup:

In MyController.js:

```
$scope.isLoaded = function() {
    $scope.$emit("myControllerLoaded");
}
```

In markup:

```
<div><!-- the content --></div>
{{isLoaded()}}
```

In app.js

```
$rootScope.$on("myControllerLoaded", function(event) {
    if ($rootScope.notification === "someEventCode") {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("openTheModel");
        delete $rootScope.notification;
    }
});
```

This seems like cumbersome and inefficient code. `isLoaded()` is called multiple times (not sure why) and it is kind of spaghetti code.

My question is - how should I implement something like that in a clear and efficient manner? Just a reminder, the app could be "cold started" or in the background and I need to know when it is "running" (or the controller is ready).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a slightly more robust, timeout based implementation (still not exactly what I was hoping for).

The idea is to set a flag and send (broadcast) the signal after some time. Then resend the signal on interval until the flag is unset by the target controller:

In app.js

```
function broadcastSomeEvent() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("someEventCode");
    if ($rootScope.eventFlag) {
        setTimeout(broadcastSomeEvent, 50);
    }
}


onNotification() {
   // some code for determining the type of notification, then
   $rootScope.eventFlag = true;
   setTimeout(broadcastSomeEvent, 10); // or 1000 in case of cold start
}
```

In MyController.js

```
$scope.$on('someEventCode', function() {
    delete $rootScope.eventFlag;  // delete flag so event is stopped
    $scope.openMyModal();
});
```

This is still an iff-y implementation to my taste. Even though it does work for both cold start and when the application is in the background I believe that it is not robust as it should.

Still, I wouldn't mark this solution as "the answer".

On the other hand, with no proper state routing, maybe there's not much more than can be done.